# Pygame using sprite sheet : alpha problems

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using a sprite sheet to animate my player, the animation works well but there isn't alpha when I blit the corresponding image of the animation on the screen.

```
Class Animation:
    def __init__(self, path, img_size):
        self.images = pyagme.image.load(path).convert_alpha()
        self.cur_img = 0
        ....

    def get_image(self):
        img=pygame.Surface((self.img_width,self.img_height)).convert_alpha()
        rect = pygame.Rect((self.cur_img * self.img_width, 0),(self.img_width, self.img_height))
        img.blit(self.images, (0, 0), rect)
        return img
```

I'm using the `get_image` funtion to draw the player : 
At each update : `self.image = self.cur_anim.get_image()`. `self` is the Player class.

In my function `draw` : `self.screen.blit(self.player.image, self.player.rect)`

Comment: new Surface is never transparent and you have to `fill()` it with RGBA color which has `A=0` - see example [transparency](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/transparency). But you can use [Surface.subsurface](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface) to create `img` and you don't need new `Surface`. BTW you could create all subsurfaces in `__init__` and keep on list and then you can get `img = self.all_images[self.cur_img]` - see example [spritesheet](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/pygame/spritesheet/main.py)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New `Surface` is never transparent so you have to fill it with `RGBA` color which has `A=0` to make it transparent.

```
img = pygame.Surface((self.img_width,self.img_height)).convert_alpha()

img.fill( (0,0,0,0) )
```

But there is [pygame.Surface.subsurface](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface) which can create subimages (and it doesn't use new memory)

```
def get_image(self):
    rect = pygame.Rect((self.cur_img * self.img_width, 0),(self.img_width, self.img_height))

    return self.images.subsurface(rect)
```

BTW: you could create all subsurfaces in `__init__` and later use only

```
def get_image(self):
    return self.all_subsurfaces[self.cur_img]
```

Comment: You can also pass `pygame.SRCALPHA` to get a transparent surface with per-pixel alpha: `img = pygame.Surface((self.img_width, self.img_height), pygame.SRCALPHA)`.